# 502 Bad Gateway Error in Django, nginx, DigitalOcean, Gunicorn but only sometimes

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am working on a Django app deployed on DigitalOcean with Gunicorn, Nginx, Postgres. Everything working fine but I am facing a strange problem of `502 Bad Gateway` only sometimes when I generate PDF using `xhtml2pdf`.

However, the problem isn't constant, it shows only sometimes. My Nginx and Gunicorn timeout is set to 30s but the error comes within 30s.

This is my code where I am generating PDFs,

```
def link_callback(uri, rel):
    # use short variable names
    sUrl    = settings.STATIC_URL      # Typically /static/
    sRoot   = settings.STATIC_ROOT    # Typically /home/userX/project_static/
    mUrl    = settings.MEDIA_URL       # Typically /static/media/
    mRoot   = settings.MEDIA_ROOT     # Typically /home/userX/project_static/media/

    # convert URIs to absolute system paths
    if uri.startswith(mUrl):
        path = os.path.join(mRoot, uri.replace(mUrl, ""))
    elif uri.startswith(sUrl):
        path = os.path.join(sRoot, uri.replace(sUrl, ""))

    # make sure that file exists
    if not os.path.isfile(path):
        raise Exception('media URI must start with %s or %s' % (sUrl, mUrl))
    return path

def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html     = template.render(context_dict)
    result   = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result, link_callback=link_callback)
    if not pdf.err:
        if for_mail:
            return result.getvalue()
        else:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None
```

I am also showing logos on generated PDFs, hence the `link_callback` function.

I don't think the problem is from Nginx or gunicorn's config files, as it should work always or not at all. Also, the problem comes only when I convert HTML to PDF and not in any other section.

It was working fine till yesterday. I don't have any idea of what went wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: anything in your nginx error.log? 502 bad gateway sounds like the backend closes the connection while nginx is waiting for an answer? Are you able to reproduce this error? If so and the error.log is not helpfull turn on debugging to check the reponsecode from your proxied application.

Comment: try increase gunicorn timeout for requests

Comment: the problem was with .png format logos, I tried converting HTML to pdf without the logo and with .jpg format and everything worked fine. Though, I have also increased gunicorn timeout